# Logback file error: no applicable action for [configuration], current ElementPath is [[configuration][configuration]]

Tags: logging, logback

I am trying the configure the logback as below but it throws me this error. The configuration file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" debug="false">
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="mediator" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <file>logs/mediator/cbs_mediator_rapid.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/mediator/cbs_mediator_rapid_%d{yyyyMMdd}_%d{HHmmss,aux}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="com.bosch.cbs.util.log.StartupSizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>250MB</maxFileSize>
            </TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="activemq" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <file>logs/activemq/cbs_mediator_rapid_activemq.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/activemq/cbs_mediator_rapid_activemq_%d{yyyyMMdd}_%d{HHmmss,aux}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="com.bosch.cbs.util.log.StartupSizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>250MB</maxFileSize>
            </TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.bosch.cbs.mediator" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="mediator" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.activemq" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="activemq" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.activemq.spring" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="activemq" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="mediator" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

------so on------

I get the following error.

```
16:56:48,212 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@2:42 - no applicable action for [configuration], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration]]
16:56:48,212 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:74 - no applicable action for [appender], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration][appender]]
16:56:48,213 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@6:18 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration][appender][encoder]]
16:56:48,213 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@7:22 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration][appender][encoder][pattern]]
```

I have surfed through stackoverflow and correct a few mistakes in this. But it still does not work. Please help!!

Comment: what options are launching your java programme with ?

Comment: Is that your entire logback.xml? There is no root-tag 'configuration' in the file?

Answer (score 13):

if you are using spring-boot then you have to use. Define your logbacks separately and include them. See [details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3503) for the issue.
**logback-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<springProfile name="staging, production">
    <include resource="logback-production.xml"/>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="dev">
        <include resource="logback-dev.xml"/>
</springProfile>

</configuration>
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3503