# ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter- no applicable action for [maxHistory]

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-logback

When using spring boot in my application, I am getting below error while starting the spring boot application main method.

Please note that  **application is running in kotlin** and we are triggering spring boot start up from a separate class. when I run the application from workspace it run successfully and start up but launching the application from a packaged  jar throws this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@20:21 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][maxHistory]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@37:21 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][maxHistory]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@54:21 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][maxHistory]]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:222)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
```

without using spring boot it is working absolutely fine. I saw this post
[Logback file error: no applicable action for [configuration], current ElementPath is [[configuration][configuration]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607031/logback-file-error-no-applicable-action-for-configuration-current-elementpat) but it didn't help.

### logback.xml:

The  tag in the logback is creating the issue how to resolve it ?

```
<appender name="HealthRollingFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${app.logpath:-log}/${log.base.name}-health.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${app.logpath:-log}/${log.base.name}-health-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>


        <!-- Number of days of log files to keep -->
        <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
    </appender>
```

My pom has multiple dependencies but below are some springboot dependencies which this code uses:

org.springframework.boot
            spring-boot
            2.3.4.RELEASE

````
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>```
        <version>5.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
````

I checked multiple posts on this forum but there doesn't seems to be a solution fitting in this case. without springboot the application running fine.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `logback` file as follows:

```
<appender name="HealthRollingFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${app.logpath:-log}/${log.base.name}-health.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${app.logpath:-log}/${log.base.name}-health-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- Number of days of log files to keep -->
        <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
             <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
     </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```